# Rotate the Hue of an imported image

Tags: color, image, rotation

I have an image,

[image: Imported image]

I want to rotate the hue of the image and export the result. Eventually I will loop this to produce ~360 images covering the entire cycle. I feel like this should be easy with Mathematica but I am struggling.

So far I have tried:

```
conv[pix_,i_]:={Mod[pix[[1]]+(i/360.),1.0],pix[[2]],pix[[3]]}
convL2[row_,i_]:=conv[#,i]&/@row;

Table[Image[convL2[#, i] & /@ ImageData[ColorConvert[base, "HSB"]]], {i, 0, 360,120}]
```

Which produces these images,

[image: Not Correct]

Which clearly aren't quite right. Does anyone have any nice methods to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `ImageApply[conv[#, 120] &, ColorConvert[base, "HSB"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahul has posted an answer in the comments to my question that solves the problem. I am posting it here to mark the question as closed.

```
conv[pix_,i_]:={Mod[pix[[1]]+(i/360.),1.0],pix[[2]],pix[[3]]}
Table[
    ImageApply[conv[#, i] &, ColorConvert[base, "HSB"]],
    {i,0,360,120}
]
```

The missing component was `ImageApply`, which `Map`s a function over every pixel of an image.